# Does updating the list take extra space?

Tags: python, space-complexity

I have an `array or list`,
Now I want to make some changes in the array and put in back to the `arr` `variable/list`. Am I using extra space? or it is the same variable gets updated again?

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]
print arr[2:] + arr[:2] # Is is using extra space
#or
arr = arr[2:] + arr[:2] # Is is using extra space
#or
arr = [1,2,3,4]
arr = arr # are not they both same? LHS arr is different from RHS arr
```

Comment: What do you mean with "LHS arr is different from RHS arr"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when assigning like this:

```
arr = arr[2:] + arr[:2]
```

you're creating a new reference of `arr`, and the old one is destroyed. Means allocation/deletion.

You should do *slice assignment*:

```
arr[:] = arr[2:] + arr[:2]
```

`arr` keeps the same reference, and if the size doesn't change, no memory allocaton occurs for `arr` (but the right hand side sum & slicing still needs allocation)

Demo:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]
old_arr = arr
arr = arr[2:] + arr[:2]
print(old_arr is arr)
```

result: `False`

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]
old_arr = arr
arr[:] = arr[2:] + arr[:2]
print(old_arr is arr)
```

result: `True`

Answer (score 0):

`<1,2,3,4>` are stored somewhere in memory. `arr` has references to `<1,2,3,4>` and `arr[2:]` has references to the same `<3,4>` that `arr` has references to.

For a list of numbers, you're using extra space for those references but not the numbers themselves.

For a list of high profile objects this actually becomes a more memory efficient means to dealing with it.

I suggest reading through this:
http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/